# Adium not connecting to MSN any more

Tags: skype, windows-live-messenger, adium

I had been using Adium for a while and had no problems connecting to MSN.

Understand that MSN had ceased operation and is forcing us to use Skype.

That I suppose is the reason why I'm not able to connect to MSN through Adium now.

This is the error message I got: `Error: Windows Live ID authentication:Invalid response`

So my question is, is there a way to work around this? Or is Skype our only solution now?

Using Adium 1.5.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem until just now. I do not know the reason for failure, but I know that if you log into live.com website is solved:)

I found the solution here: https://trac.adium.im/ticket/11236

Luck.